# (Python) Is there a way to extract substrings/numbers from an entire string?

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

I have a list of tuples containing unique utility data including Consumption (Cubic Feet), Gallons of Water, and Estimated Price. There are 13 tuples, one for each month of the year and one for total consumption at the end of the year. My goal is to extract these three pieces of information, store them into a dataframe, and eventually export them into an Excel Sheet.

This is what the list of tuples look like after I sorted them as strings. (The reason I iterated and sorted them as strings is because they were originally a Soup(BeautifulSoup) format and made it hard to organize into a list.)

Here is what one tuple looks like:

```
[\'<area alt="" coords="151,115,181,382" onmouseout="DisplayTooltip(\\\'\\\');" onmouseover="DisplayTooltip(\\\'Consumption = 49,094.00 CF (367,223.12 Gallons)  &lt;br /&gt; Approximate Charge = $5,073.42\\\');" shape="rect"/>\']'
```

Below is the entire list of Tuples. The only exception is that the final (13th) tuple lists 'Total Consumption' instead of just 'Consumption'

```
['[\'<area alt="" coords="113,88,143,382" onmouseout="DisplayTooltip(\\\'\\\');" onmouseover="DisplayTooltip(\\\'**Consumption = 54,070.00 CF (404,443.60 Gallons)**  &lt;br /&gt; **Approximate Charge = $5,587.65**\\\');" shape="rect"/>\']', '[\'<area alt="" coords="151,115,181,382" onmouseout="DisplayTooltip(\\\'\\\');" onmouseover="DisplayTooltip(\\\'Consumption = 49,094.00 CF (367,223.12 Gallons)  &lt;br /&gt; Approximate Charge = $5,073.42\\\');" shape="rect"/>\']', '[\'<area alt="" coords="188,99,218,382" onmouseout="DisplayTooltip(\\\'\\\');" onmouseover="DisplayTooltip(\\\'Consumption = 51,921.00 CF (388,369.08 Gallons)  &lt;br /&gt; Approximate Charge = $5,365.57\\\');" shape="rect"/>\']', '[\'<area alt="" coords="226,125,256,382" onmouseout="DisplayTooltip(\\\'\\\');" onmouseover="DisplayTooltip(\\\'Consumption = 47,122.00 CF (352,472.56 Gallons)  &lt;br /&gt; Approximate Charge = $4,869.63\\\');" shape="rect"/>\']', '[\'<area alt="" coords="263,101,294,382" onmouseout="DisplayTooltip(\\\'\\\');" onmouseover="DisplayTooltip(\\\'Consumption = 51,687.00 CF (386,618.76 Gallons)  &lt;br /&gt; Approximate Charge = $5,341.39\\\');" shape="rect"/>\']', '[\'<area alt="" coords="301,139,331,382" onmouseout="DisplayTooltip(\\\'\\\');" onmouseover="DisplayTooltip(\\\'Consumption = 44,643.00 CF (333,929.64 Gallons)  &lt;br /&gt; Approximate Charge = $4,613.45\\\');" shape="rect"/>\']', '[\'<area alt="" coords="339,176,369,382" onmouseout="DisplayTooltip(\\\'\\\');" onmouseover="DisplayTooltip(\\\'Consumption = 37,770.00 CF (282,519.60 Gallons)  &lt;br /&gt; Approximate Charge = $4,010.80\\\');" shape="rect"/>\']', '[\'<area alt="" coords="376,382,407,383" onmouseout="DisplayTooltip(\\\'\\\');" onmouseover="DisplayTooltip(\\\'Consumption = 0.00 CF (0.00 Gallons)  &lt;br /&gt; Approximate Charge = $0.00\\\');" shape="rect"/>\']', '[\'<area alt="" coords="414,382,444,383" onmouseout="DisplayTooltip(\\\'\\\');" onmouseover="DisplayTooltip(\\\'Consumption = 0.00 CF (0.00 Gallons)  &lt;br /&gt; Approximate Charge = $0.00\\\');" shape="rect"/>\']', '[\'<area alt="" coords="452,382,482,383" onmouseout="DisplayTooltip(\\\'\\\');" onmouseover="DisplayTooltip(\\\'Consumption = 0.00 CF (0.00 Gallons)  &lt;br /&gt; Approximate Charge = $0.00\\\');" shape="rect"/>\']', '[\'<area alt="" coords="489,382,519,383" onmouseout="DisplayTooltip(\\\'\\\');" onmouseover="DisplayTooltip(\\\'Consumption = 0.00 CF (0.00 Gallons)  &lt;br /&gt; Approximate Charge = $0.00\\\');" shape="rect"/>\']', '[\'<area alt="" coords="527,382,557,383" onmouseout="DisplayTooltip(\\\'\\\');" onmouseover="DisplayTooltip(\\\'Consumption = 0.00 CF (0.00 Gallons)  &lt;br /&gt; Approximate Charge = $0.00\\\');" shape="rect"/>\']', '[\'<area alt="" coords="653,68,733,382" onmouseout="DisplayTooltip(\\\'\\\');" onmouseover="DisplayTooltip(\\\'Total Consumption = 336,307 CF (2,515,576 Gallons) &lt;br /&gt; Approximate Charge = $34,861.91\\\');" shape="rect"/>\']']
```

I wrote this Regex expression to extract gallons:

```py
gallons = re.search('CF((.*)Gallons)', test_line)
print(gallons)
```

Which outputs this:

```
<re.Match object; span=(128, 150), match='CF (404,443.60 Gallons'>
```

This doesn't really make it any easier as now I have to find a way to extract '404,443,.60'

If anyone may recommend a way to extract those three pieces of data from the list of tuples (assuming I will most likely have to create some form of iteration on the list of tuples) and store them into a dataframe that'd be very helpful. The end goal is to store those numbers into a dataframe and eventually export into an Excel sheet.

Answer (score 3):

This might do what you want:

```
gallons = re.search(r'(?<=CF\s\()[\d,\.]*(?= Gallons)', test_line)
```

Comment: You want the beginning `r` to be *outside* the quotes, not inside. FTFY.

Comment: Thanks! I was on mobile so those things happen :'D

Comment: The match was successful thank you! However, when I print gallons it returns the entire "<re.Match object; span=(132, 142), match='404,443.60'> " is there a way to return only the number?

Comment: Use the group method on the match object gallons: `gallons.group()`

Comment: Did it solve your problem? Please let us know if you're still facing an issue or mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the matched group:

```py
import re
re_gallons = re.compile(r'CF \((.*)Gallons\)')
print(re_gallons.search(test_line).group(1))
```

Comment: thank you this works but im having trouble incorporating it into an iteration loop

Comment: You could add each re to a list and iter over it, saving each match to a results list.

Comment: If you post more of the code it would be helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the capture group, and make the pattern a bit more specific by matching the parenthesis and capture the digits with optional decimal parts after the opening parenthesis in group 1.

```
\bCF\s\((\d+(?:\.\d+)*(?:,\d+(?:\.\d+)*)*)\sGallons\)
```

- `\bCF\s` A word boundary to prevent an empty match, Match `CF` and a whitespace char
- `\(` Match `(`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)*` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
  - `(?:,\d+(?:\.\d+)*)*` Optionally repeat matching `,` and 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `)` Close group 1
- `\sGallons\)` Match a whitespace char and `Gallons)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ke1mtt/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/30H36N)

For example

```
import re
 
pattern=r"\bCF\s\((\d+(?:\.\d+)*(?:,\d+(?:\.\d+)*)*)\sGallons\)"
 
strings = [r'Consumption = 49,094.00 CF (367,223.12 Gallons)']
 
for s in strings:
    m = re.search(pattern, s)
    if m:
      gallons = m.group(1)
      print(gallons)
```

Output

```
367,223.12
```